# Cannot access sharedPrefrences from Xposed

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, java-io, xposed

I have an App that contains an xposed module in the App there is recyclerView and in each View in it there is a check button once checked it should save that it's checked and save an object to an arraylist then this Arraylist is saved in sharedPrefrences, I tried accessing shared preferences in the module using XSharedPrefrences but it didn't work I always get the default value which is null

```
  XSharedPreferences pref = new XSharedPreferences(MyClass.class.getPackage().getName(),Storage);
            pref.makeWorldReadable();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = pref.getString("ApplicationArrayList", null);
            XposedBridge.log(json);
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ApplicationPOJO>>() {
            }.getType();
            packages =  gson.fromJson(json,type);
```

the code that's used to save the arraylist is as follows

```
   public void storeApplicationInfo(ArrayList<ApplicationPOJO> arrayList) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Storage, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(arrayList);
        editor.putString("ApplicationArrayList", json);
        editor.apply();
    }
```